# Wireshark not displaying request packets

Tags: wireshark, packets

I am using Wireshark v1.8.3 on Windows 7 and I am sending a ping with cmd to see the packets on Wireshark. The reply packets are being displayed but the request packets are not being shown. Do I have some sort of filter which I need to remove?

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem - my firewall was blocking the request packets.